# javascript coordinate movement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id='btn'>CLICK ME</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="400">
      

    </canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
let x = 50;
let y = 50;

let c = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,40,0,2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

let button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = function(event) {
  if(event.which == 1) {
    x += 5;
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

I made a Circle `CTX`, I wanted it to move when I click the button, But when I click it nothing happens so I tried logging in the console if the `X` variable  is changing when I click the button and it is changing but still the Circle won't move. Is there any problem? Is there any other way to make the circle move?

Comment: The canvas is never re-drawn

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your not redrawing the canvas with the new data, you should create a main function and update x amount of times per second, or update it when you change things.

```js
let x = 50;
let y = 50;

let c = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,40,0,2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}
draw()

let button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = function(event) {
  if(event.which == 1) {
    x += 5;
    draw()
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id='btn'>CLICK ME</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="400">
      

    </canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```